# Powershell script saving on UTC time

Tags: powershell, csv, sharepoint, time

i had implemented powershell script for extract data from sharepoint to CSV file. Currently my file was saving as per my time zone. But i want to save the file with UTC time. means under script i want to convert time format my time to UTC time.  Can anyone please correct my script. Below script lines i am using.

```
 Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$web = get-spweb http://testsharepoint/sharepoint/
$caseLib = $web.lists | where {$_.title -eq "Library"}

$query=new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery 

$query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='LinkFilename'/><FieldRef Name='DocumentSetDescription'/>"

$query.RowLimit=5000

$ListName1 = "Test_"
$ExportFolder1 = “C:\export\”
$ExportName1 = Get-Date -f “yyyyMMdd”
$ExportPath1 = $ExportFolder1 + $ListName1 + $ExportName1 + “.csv”

$ListName = "Data_"
$ExportFolder = “\\servername\Data\”
$ExportName = Get-Date -f “yyyyMMdd”
$ExportPath = $ExportFolder + $ListName + $ExportName + “.csv”

do
{
$caseLibItems=$caseLib.GetItems($query)
$query.ListItemCollectionPosition=$caseLibItems.ListItemCollectionPosition
$listItemsTotal = $caseLibItems.Count
$x = 0
for($x=0;$x -lt $listItemsTotal; $x++)
{
$Description = $caseLibItems[$x]["DocumentSetDescription"]
$str = ""
if('$Description; -ne $null)
$str = $caseLibItems[$x]["LinkFilename"].ToString() + '}' + $Description 
  }
else
 {
$str = $caseLibItems[$x]["LinkFilename"].ToString()
}
Write-Output $str| Out-File $ExportPath1 -Append
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite easy as PowerShell has a [`.ToUniversalTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.touniversaltime) method. Changing the below would be the easiest without changing everything else.

```
$ExportName = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMdd")
$ExportName1 = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMdd")
```

Comment: It is the underlying .NET library that has this method. For the sake of completeness - there are as well built-in format strings: [standard date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) and [custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)